# How to bulk select all objects while also exclude things like Empties in a large collection

Tags: uv

I have a collection of about 200 objects and about half of them are parented and nested to Empties that drive the overall collections' animation.

As you know, to unwrap the objects I need to select each object and unwrap them while in edit mode.

In a perfect world I'd do this process once, but, in reality, there is always some need to fix some issue with the mesh found during the unwrap process, or, just as the project progresses, and once mesh changes are made, I need to then to CTRl-Click select each objects one by one, unwrap again, fix, reselect -- etc... as you can see this is painful and very time consuming.

I thought of hiding the empties, but then I have to go in and unhide them for other processes. So that strategy does not scale when as in my case; as said, I have a high quantity of objects and empties in my collection. Collection> select Objects selects everything including the empties which then prevents edit mode to allow unwrapping.

Is there a way to quickly and efficiently pick out/select objects ONLY from within a collection that highlights them from everything else that's visible within a collection?
Thanks.

Comment: Select a mesh object, hit Shift+G and select Type.

Comment: Works!   One more question... Is there a similar quick way to select all objects in a collection that have the same material assignment?

Comment: Yes. Shift+L>>Material.